# Website Starts to Load, then Stops

Tags: joomla, pageload

This problem just started occurring, no recent changes have been made. However, when you load the URL, the page begins to load and thens stops and seems to continue to try to load - but never actually loads the page.

http://goo.gl/7VhhK

Any idea what could be tripping it up ?

Comment: After half a minute it loaded the webpage

Comment: Are there any errors being stored in the error log? Turn on the Joomla debugging tool and make sure that there are not multiple libraries being loaded such as jQuery

Comment: loadSkin is not defined as well as srfp

Comment: It appears as if their was a conflicting script. After disabling the SRFP script, things seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked your website by 'net' tab by firebug on firefox 17.0.1
and all requests in server works correctly ,  no  files corrupted and no ignored requested so you don't have any problem in files or server
but you have this problem in console

> Shadowbox.loadSkin is not a function

just delete repeated jQuery script links
and put  no conflict code

> jQuery.noConflict();